# PyQt4 - QPushbutton.setIcon doesn't set the icon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I am writing an open configurable taskbar using PyQt4, and I want to add a start orb. I want the orb to support the common image format of start orbs, which is usually three 54x54 squares for a 54x162 image.

My program takes those images, cuts them in thirds using PIL, and I try to load them using `.setIcon(QIcon(icon))`. Unfortunately, this isn't working. The image is loaded, calling `.show()` displays the image perfectly.

For various reasons, I did not choose style sheets, including that I would have trouble loading the cut images. Instead, (as the code shows) I had the QPushButton change icons on hover, press, and release. None of them work. Not even the default image.

My code is on [this github](https://github.com/IronManMark20/PyExplorer). Note the warning in the readme! The program quite literally replaces (and removes) the taskbar (but you can get it back).

tl;dr

I have the code (see link below). It won't load using .setIcon(), and I don't know why. I thought it would work, used `ImageQt`, but no.

**EDIT**:Unfortunately, going from a PIL object to a Imagqt object to a QImage didn't solve the problem. 
**EDIT2**: as @Trilarion requeted here is a link to a gist of the slimmed down code: https://gist.github.com/IronManMark20/85b00104c9bb52b78add

Comment: This is quite a lot of code. Could you cut it down to give a minimal example showing the problem?

Comment: Added edit @Trilarion see example in gist. Is that short enough?